# how to specify duration in live m3u8 stream using ffmpeg?

Tags: stream, ffmpeg

I want to specify a duration for example 4 min when using ffmpeg but i keep getting error:

```
ffmpeg -i "./test.m3u8" -t 04:00 "output.mp4"
```

and error i get is this:

```
Invalid duration specification for t: 04:00
```

also these warnings in yellow color:

```
max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5014800
 Could not find codec parameters (Video: h264 (
 Could not find codec parameters (Audio: aac (
 Could not find codec parameters (Video: h264 (
Could not find codec parameters (Audio: aac (
```

hope you guys help me what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> `duration` may be a number in seconds, or in `hh:mm:ss[.xxx]` form.

Your form is `mm:ss`, so it's simply not valid. Which is also what the error message says.

Use `-t 00:04:00` or `-t 240` instead.